# Can a composition of a continuous nowhere differentiable and a nonconstant differentiable function be differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous and nowhere differentiable, and $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable everywhere and non constant. Can $f \circ g$ ever be differentiable?

My intuition is no, but I'm not sure. Perhaps $g$ is differentiable but not continuously so and its derivative behaves badly enough that somehow things could get smoothed out. I highly doubt this is possible but I don't see how to prove it.

Edit: based on the comments, I'd like to additionally specify that g be nonconstant on any interval.

Comment: You can have $g$ differentiable but be constant on an interval.

Comment: Good point. But would it ever be possible for $f \circ g$ to be everywhere differentiable?

Comment: @Randall's point is that $f\circ g$ can be constant by having $g$ constant on an interval and $f$ have range contained in that interval. You probably want to add that $g$ isn't constant on any interval.